# Angular - I can't make a class-property?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am learning Angular.. for the Search I want to use a Service that sends and recieves data via websockets.

I have created a service with angular-cli:

```
ng -g-s websocketsService
```

Now this is my websockets.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';


@Injectable()
export class WebsocketsService {

    private _search: string;
    private url = 'ws://localhost:1337';

    constructor() {
    }

    sendQuery(search) {
        this._search = search;
        console.log('Perform search for: ' + this._search);

        const websocket = new WebSocket(this.url);

        websocket.onopen = () => {
            websocket.send(JSON.stringify({
                data: this._search
            }));
        };

        websocket.onmessage = function (event) {
            console.log(event.data);
        };

        websocket.onerror = function (event) {
            console.log('A Error has occured!');
        };

        websocket.onclose = function (event) {
            console.log('Connection closed');
        };
    }
}
```

so far so good.. this works.. but this seems not like best-practice to me.. I would like to have the websocket-connection as a class-property so I could establish a connection in one mehtod and send data in a other method..

but when I define a variable in the class like `private ws;` and then try to hanle it with `this.ws` I always get a error that this.ws is undefined (?)

what am I doing wrong here? how could I get this a little prettier?

this is one simple try, that does not work and I don't understand why:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';


@Injectable()
export class WebsocketsService {

  private _search: string;
  private url = 'ws://localhost:1337';

  public wsConnection;

  constructor() {
    this.create();
  }

  create() {
    this.wsConnection = new WebSocket(this.url);
  }

  sendQuery(search) {
    this._search = search;
    console.log('Perform search for: ' + this._search);


    this.wsConnection.onopen = () => {
      this.wsConnection.send(JSON.stringify({
        data: this._search
      }));
    };
```

}
}

the connection gets established, but in the sendQuery()-method the send() does not work.. i also get no error in the console.

Comment: Could you post the version of the code that does not work ? In principle there should not be a problem with making it a class field, you just need to initialize before you use it

Comment: thanks, i have udated the question with a try that fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export class CustomWebSocket {

  websocket: WebSocket;

  constructor(
    private url: string
  ) {
    this.websocket = new WebSocket(url);
  }

  sendQuery(search: string) {
    websocket.onopen = () => websocket.send(JSON.stringify({ data: search }));
    websocket.onmessage = event => console.log(event.data);
    websocket.onerror = event => console.log('A Error has occured!');
    websocket.onclose = event => console.log('Connection closed');
  }
}
```

In your service :

```
export class WebsocketsService {
  public sockets: CustomWebSocket[] = [];
  constructor() {}
  createWS(url: string): CustomWebSocket {
    const ws = new CustomWebSocket(url);
    this.sockets.push(ws);
    return ws;
  }
}
```

In your component :

```
this.myService.createWS('url').sendQuery('my query');
```

I believe this is the cleanest way of doing it, but it's my personal opinion.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, you have to initialize your websocket (with its event callbacks) member first in your constructor and use it in the class methods.

```
@Injectable()
export

class WebsocketsService {

  private _search:string;
  private url ='ws://localhost:1337';
  private websocket:WebSocket;

  constructor() {
    this.websocket = new WebSocket(this.url);
    this.websocket.onopen = function() {
      console.log('Connection opened');
    };

    this.websocket.onmessage = function(event) {
      console.log(event.data);
    };

    this.websocket.onerror = function(event) {
      console.log('A Error has occured!');
    };

    this.websocket.onclose = function(event) {
      console.log('Connection closed');
    };
  }

  sendQuery(search) {
    this._search = search;
    console.log('Perform search for: ' + this._search);

    this.websocket.send(JSON.stringify({
      data:this._search
            }));
  }
}
```

EDIT:
For each websocket send method call, if the server close the connection, we can't use the send method afterward. 
We have to use the onopen handler to send data. Each call create its own websocket and send data when the connection state is OPEN.

```
@Injectable()
export

class WebsocketsService {

  private _search:string;
  private url ='ws://localhost:1337';

  constructor() {
  }

  sendQuery(search) {
    this._search = search;
    console.log('Perform search for: ' + this._search);

    let websocket = new WebSocket(this.url);
    websocket.onopen = function() {
      console.log('Connection opened');
      websocket.send(JSON.stringify({
          data:this._search
      }));
    };

    websocket.onmessage = function(event) {
      console.log(event.data);
    };

    websocket.onerror = function(event) {
      console.log('A Error has occured!');
    };

    websocket.onclose = function(event) {
      console.log('Connection closed');
    };   
  }
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for you reply..  I have tried this, although I have tried it like this before.. but it does not work.. i get a DOM error .. oO  ..I also don't understand why the callbacks should be initialized in the constructor? could you please explain?

Comment: Callbacks have to be initialized once, and probably the best place is in the constructor (you can initialize them elsewhere if you want). Can you add the "dom error" ?

Comment: .. sure: `DOMException
code: 11
columnNumber: 0
data: null
filename: "webpack-internal:///../../../../../src/app/services/websockets/websockets.service.ts"
lineNumber: 36
message: "An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable"
name: "InvalidStateError"
ngDebugContext: Object { view: {…}, nodeIndex: 19, nodeDef: {…}, … }
ngErrorLogger: function bound ()
result: 2152923147
stack: "WebsocketsService.prototype.sendQuery@webpack-internal:///../../../../../src/app/services/websockets/websockets.service.ts:3...`

Comment: Well, if I don't have your code I can't tell you what's wrong with it !!! Please take a look to the MDN WS client sample [here](https://github.com/mdn/samples-server/blob/master/s/websocket-chat/chatclient.js) and good luck !!!

Comment: Yep, if you copy/paste it's ok to me. Maybe it's due to your server that previously closed the connection. I updated my answer. Best.